# laravel 4.2 migration memory issue

Tags: php, memory, eloquent, migration, laravel-4.2

I have few migrations which are something like this:

```
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
SomeModel::withTrashed()->chunk(500, function($first) {      
  var_dump(memory_get_usage());      
  foreach ($first as $first2) {        
    if(!count($first2->country)) {
      $first2->forceDelete();
    }
  }
});
```

and after every migration my memory keep increasing. For example, when Im running previous migration my memory increasing, results:

```
int(19883832)
int(20622848)
int(21075088)
int(21535400)
int(21987912)
...
```

And after few migrations im getting such error: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Is it possible somehow to clear memory after each migration or I need increase memory with ini_set(’memory_limit’, ‘512M’); ?